# Erro ao formatar CEP com a função Format()

Tags: sql-server

Ao tentar formatar os dados da variável CEP, o SQL Server retorna a seguinte mensagem:

***Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.***

Segue o meu código:

```
DECLARE @cep VARCHAR(9) = '23574510';
SELECT FORMAT(@cep,'#####-###') AS [CEP]
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: a função `FORMAT` só aceita numeros e datas como parâmetro: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Obrigada Ricardo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `FORMAT` aceita apenas os tipos numéricos e tipos de data. Você poderia fazer assim:

```
DECLARE @cep int = 23574510;
SELECT FORMAT(@cep,'#####-###') AS [CEP]
```